# Unable to connect to sql server xcode objective-c

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, xcode, sockets

Hi i'm using mbmysql db and trying to connect to my server ;) The problem is that i get this error while trying to do so:

Error Connection:Can't connect to MySQL server on 'www.car-iran.com' (60)

According to what i googled i should set things like this:

```
db.socket = NULL;
db.serverName = @"www.car-iran.com";
db.dbName = @"cariranc_cariran";
db.userName = @"*******";
db.password = @"********";
db.port = 2082;
```

i've read the library itself and know how it's connecting using mysql real connect! i've tried different values for socket and serverName like:
`socket  ="localhost"` ,socket or `serverName="http://173.25.101.200:2082/"` ,  serverName or `socket ="http://173.25.101.200/"` `socket = "/var/mysql/mysql.sock"`

Comment: serverName must be static ip so...